# How can I test if a bivariate correlation is significantly different from a partial correlation?

Tags: pearson-r, partial-effect

I have three variables (A, T, C) with n= 1083. The Pearson correlations are as below:

A*T= .170  (p<.01)
A*C= .370  (p<.01)
T*C= -.103 (p<.01)

Partial correlation between A and T controlling for C = .225 (p<.01)

I would like to know if the increase in A*T (r= .170) is significantly different from partial r (.225). How can I test this?